# How to set up Miracast on Windows 8.1?

Tags: windows-8.1-preview, miracast

My "dumb" TV and my WD TV Live Hub both do not support Miracast (this is a technology to display your phone or table on an external screen). Windows 8.1 is said to support it, however, so I've installed 8.1 Preview on my laptop, gone to set up Screen Mirroing on my Xperia Z1...and it can't find any devices. I've disabled the Windows firewall tempoarily and had a look at sharing options in Windows Media Player (which is said to support it).

What am I missing?

HP ProBook 4510s, running Windows 8.1 Preview. No extra apps installed. Sony Xperia Z1 running Android 4.2.2.

Comment: There is a guide on HTG [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/200897/how-to-use-miracast-screen-mirroring-from-windows-or-android/) dealing with Miracast, Android 4.2+ and Windows 8. Have you checked it?

Answer (score 2):

Miracast uses a WiFi Direct connection. WiFi Direct has been supported with Intel network cards for a very long time, advertised as “My Wifi”. Because all WiFi Direct depends on is hosting a Software Access Point, it can be used with most WiFi cards/chipsets.

Windows 8.1 however, has more specific requirements. For Miracast to be usable, your network driver has to support NDIS 6.4. Because existing drivers supporting older NDIS versions continue to work, most manufacturers don’t bother upgrading, especially with older hardware.

It also requires WDDM 1.3 display drivers. Because all relevant GPU manufacturers use unified drivers, they are more readily available.

[All information is available in this post on the official Microsoft Windows blog](http://blogs.windows.com/bloggingwindows/2013/11/12/windows-8-1-on-your-big-screen-with-miracast/).

And then, here’s the thing for your specific use case: Windows is not a Miracast receiver. It can only transmit. Luckily, there are third party apps like [AirServer](http://www.airserver.com/) available. It’s not terribly expensive either.

I am not affiliated with AirServer’s manufacturer, App Dynamic, in any way.

#### Update

Hello Time Travelers! It's now 2017 and Windows 10 has arrived. The last part no longer applies! Using the built-in "Connect" app, Windows is also a Miracast receiver. (I never managed to get Android to connect to it though.)

Answer (score 0):

You need a wifi card on your computer that supports wifi direct. Its a feature in newer wifi cards. most that are older than a year ( before 2014 ) do not have support for wifi direct.
If your wifi card supports wifi direct than you can use miracast.

Comment: I believe this is mostly a driver issue, though. WiFi Direct is just creative use of existing resources.

Answer (score -1):

Windows 8.1 and Windows 10 support Miracast, as a sender, same as your smartphone OS, if the hardware it's running on supports it.

You want to use Windows as a receiver, which is not something offered by Windows 8.1. To do that you need to install [3rd party software](http://www.airserver.com/).

Comment: This post is awfully suspicious—the text suggests an attempt to evade spam filters (by not mentioning the name of the third-party software product). If you are affiliated with the developer, please mention your affiliation. For more information, please see http://superuser.com/help/promotion.

Comment: *Sigh* Lets not be so quick to use the S word. I do note that using a blind link like this means that part of the answer is *less* than useful should the original link go down, that a good software recommendation focuses on the process rather than the software, and it duplicates part of Daniel B's answer, with no additional useful information at all. It is, however, not having many of the less obvious characteristics of a spam post.

Comment: Note that I did not flag as spam. I assumed good faith here.

Comment: @DragonLord While it duplicates part of Daniel's answer, the point of this answer is that it has all the relevant information and is much shorter and easier to read and understand. 
The link is to the only product I know of that does what the question asked, and I didn't place the name of the product in the link exactly because I didn't want to advertise it more than necessary. Obviously I'm not affiliated with the developer.